# Civicrm views bulk operations contact delete operation not working

Tags: contact-view

I added the Civicrm tables to the settings.php according to the database integration guidlines at civicrm/admin/setting/uf?reset=1
I enabled watchdog logging for civicrm
I installed civicrm entity.
I installed views bulk operations
I selected the Civicrm contact views bulk operations field in a view, and the Delete operation.

The delete operations appear to throw no errors..but the contacts are not deleted.

What could cause this?

Comment: any log errors?

Comment: As mentioned in the question, there are no log errors.

Comment: are other things that connect civi and drupal working correctly? eg do you get civi data showing in Views?

Comment: Yes, civi data is showing in views. The fields I use are

Comment: Bulk operations: CiviCRM Contact
CiviCRM Contacts: Contact ID (Contact ID)
CiviCRM Contacts: Display Name (Display Name)
CiviCRM Email: Email Address (Email Address)
CiviCRM Phone Details: Phone Number (Phone Number)
CiviCRM Address: Country (Country)
CiviCRM Contacts: Contact Sub Type (Contact Sub Type)

Answer (score 2):

It worked when I just tested it. You should know that Civi can be configured to hold the contacts in 'trash', so they might look like they are still there, but you will notice they are marked for permanent deletion and don't show up in any reports.

You should change your View to filter by "Contact is Deleted" set to 0.